# How to find the outer most points of a Vector2 array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, geometry

I am trying to draw lines between the outer most vector2 positions from a array of random points (Like demonstrated in the images below). I am able to draw the lines although i need a algorithm that can find these points efficiently. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: you are after the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). Check some of the most popular ways to achieve that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms). I suggest that you try the gift wrapping option, one of the simplest. You can find implementations of these algorithms one google search ahead, if not in c#, maybe in python to inspire/guide you